# How to kill turtles that are over patches in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

```
to setup-lava
    ask n-of lava patches [set pcolor orange]
    ask men [die]
end
```

When I ask the men to die when they stand on a lava patch Netlogo gives me and error saying 'expected a number here, rather than a list or block'.

Comment: Almost certainly, the `ask men [die]` line is not generating the error. NetLogo highlights the problem line in yellow for most errors.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us what lava is, but the error message suggests it is not a number. If you look in the NetLogo Dictionary, you will see that `n-of` must be followed by a number and then the agentset to tell NetLogo how many of the agentset to select.

Choice 1: assumes that lava-patches is a variable with a number in it (eg a slider on your interface)

```
to setup-lava
    ask n-of lava-patches patches
    [ set pcolor orange
      ask men-here [die]
    ]
end
```

Choice 2: lava? is an attribute of patches that flags whether it is lava and that you have (somewhere else in your code) set that flag for lava patches

```
to setup-lava
    ask patches with [lava?]
    [ set pcolor orange
      ask men-here [die]
    ]
end
```

Neither of these are tested